# R - How to grep the records which have exact set of words but nothing else

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace values on Col2 based on exact set of words that I like to find in Col1.

```
Col1                   Col2
What Machine             10
What Machines            20 
What Machine Learning    30
```

When I try the following grep code with fixed = True to only to get Col2 values which have "What Machine"
as Col1,

```
d[grep("What Machine", d$Col1, fixed = T),]$Col2
```

it returns all 3 Col2 values (10 20 30).
But I really want is to get 10 as the answer and replace with the value I prefer.

Any help is so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match a single string exactly, `==` would do the trick.

```
with(d, Col2[Col1 == "What Machine"])
# [1] 10
```

If you still wanted to use `grep()`, I would suggest you switch to `grepl()` (it's safer when no matches occur) and use anchors `"^What Machine$"`, removing `fixed = TRUE` from the call.

```
with(d, Col2[grepl("^What Machine$", Col1)])
# [1] 10
```